# Dropdown menu with full width submenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am trying to create dropdown menu using Bootstrap Twitter. I need to have submenu that has width same as main menu, and is placed below it.

Bootstrap provide us only with standard dropdown menu that is placed right below the clicked li item and width dependent on this li. It is of course understandable as submenu is child of clicked li, but do you have any easy tricks to make it change?
Or the only solution is to write my own dropdown for this?

What is more, I need it responsive.

Comment: you should try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449960/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav, demo: http://www.bootply.com/E8DurpOyBi

Comment: this solution I think is the best, and is easy to apply.. take a look -> http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the CSS for the .dropdown-submenu to make it appear below its parent dropdown.

For example,

```
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu{
    left:10px;
    top:32px;
}
```

### **[Demo](http://bootply.com/60932)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add these styles to the submenu (and just substitute the sizes of padding/margin you need to match up to your parent element)

```
.dropdown-menu {
    padding:0 100%;
    margin: 0 -100%;
  }
```

[Demo](http://bootply.com/60940)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with jQuery

```
$(".dropdown-menu").css("padding","0 100%");
$(".dropdown-menu").css("margin","0 -100%");
```