# Full width Bootstrap dropdown nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to create full width dropdown using bootstrap [as you can see on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6hcZ.png). Now I have something like this (I have removed unnecessary items from the nav list):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="/_work/cz.krupovi/www/o-nas">O nás</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Kalkulačky <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu list-inline" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">RPSN Kalkulačka</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inflační kalkulačka</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to create [dropdown like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PXdy.png). I haven't done any changes to navbar and dropdown less files - this is the reason why I don't post CSS, **it's pure Bootstrap 3.2.0**. I just played with CSS rules in Chrome, disabled them and changed values of them (those that have something common with positioning).

Added my own rules but still I can't figure out how to make it 100% of viewport width. Probably it inherits width from parent which - of course - doesn't have viewport width. This could be the problem.

Also [I have found this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547665/how-to-style-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-to-be-full-page-width) but it didn't help me. I was in stage where I got about 800px width dropdown (when I used `width: 100%`), but it was aligned under "Kalkulačky" and if I wanted it to start on the left edge of the screen I had to use `left: -100px`. Do you have any ideas? I'm competently lost.

Please be benevolent - I don't have good knowledge in CSS and I just started with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a default navbar component not wrapped in a `div.container` you can use the following CSS:

```
.nav > li.dropdown.open { position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0; }
.dropdown-menu>li { display: table-cell; }
```

[demo](http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w)

The `display: table-cell` can also be replaced with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Thank you a lot, I switched to your solution and it worked for me. Sorry for delay but I haven't been here for a while and my phone didn't notify me about your answer. +1 and solved

Comment: i would recommend wrapping this in `@media (min-width:641px){ }` so the standard dropdown would still apply for mobile devices

Comment: @BassJobsen There seems to be a problem with safari, right? The sub-menu does not disappear correctly ...

Comment: i don't know. If the [demo](http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w) won't work on safari you should possible ask a new question (or buy me a mac so i can test it :) )

Comment: @BassJobse, I created a topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043487/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav-not-working-in-safari. Please, could you take a look to the print screen? Thanks!

Comment: confirmed, it doesn`t disappear correctly on latest Safari (Version 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)) - Yosemite

Comment: @Northys does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043487/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav-not-working-in-safari/30517483 fix your issue?

Comment: @BassJobsen yes, it does

Answer (score 2):

Best to use this plugin

http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

*HTML*

```
<nav class="navbar yamm navbar-default " role="navigation">
...
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
               <div class="yamm-content">
                  <div class="row"> 
                    ...
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
...
</nav>
```

*LESS*

```
/*!
 * Yamm!3 - Yet another megamenu for Bootstrap 3
 * http://geedmo.github.com/yamm3
 * 
 * @geedmo - Licensed under the MIT license
 */

//-----------------------------
//  Yamm Styles
//-----------------------------

.yamm {

  // reset positions 
  .nav, .collapse, .dropup, .dropdown {
    position: static;
  }  

  // propagate menu position under container for fw navbars
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }

  // by default aligns menu to left
  .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
  }

  // Content with padding 
  .yamm-content {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }

  // Fullwidth menu
  .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0; right: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: I used the css of the plugin for what I needed: only one option in full width, which was not possible using the plugin as is. Good resource.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this CSS, it might help.

```
 .dropdown-menu {
      min-width:auto;
      width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: It's not full viewport width.

Comment: Sorry, that should be 100%. Did you use <div class="container"> at the top of your structure?

Comment: [I have found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531654/bootstrap-3-horizontal-submenu-background-full-viewport-width/25713677#25713677) so I'm going to try it. Yes I do - container is inside `<header>`.