# Full width Bootstrap dropdown nav - Not working in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, navigation

I was looking for a way to display the "dropdown nav" with full width and luckily I found a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449960/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav/26467414#comment48158029_26467414), answered by Bass Jobse.

Unfortunately, I identified one compatibility issue with Safari browser. As you can see in the picture below, when I remove the mouse from menu link, the dropdown nav stays there, like a "ghost nav".

[image]

This bug only occurs in Safari browsers and appears to be related to property "position: static", as you can verify in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w).

Please, could someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not have the issue, but i found  other webkit browsers (tested with reconq) indeed have the issue describe above.

As far as i do understand the issue the following happens:

when removing the `open` class from `.nav > li.dropdown` its children got:
`position: relative` (parent) `display:hidden`. The area of the preceding is smaller than the width of the `position: static` (parent) `display:block`.

So when switching between open / not open Webkit does only hide the `position: relative` (parent) `display:hidden` area.

Solution apply `position: static` on both the situation with and without the `open` class:

```
.nav > li.dropdown { position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0; }
.dropdown-menu>li { display: table-cell; }
```

So use `nav > li.dropdown { position: static; }` instead of `nav > li.dropdown.open { position: static; }`