# Bootstrap 3 dropdown nav 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, navigation

I was looking for a way to display the "dropdown nav" with full width and luckily I found a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449960/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav/26467414#comment48158029_26467414).

Unfortunately, I identified one compatibility issue with Safari browser. As you can see in the picture below, when I remove the mouse from menu link, the dropdown nav stays there, like a "ghost nav".

[image]

This bug only occurs in Safari browsers and appears to be related to property "position: static", as you can verify in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w).

Please, could someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the [Yamm 3!](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/)